# How to change the resolution of data frame (not raster file) from 0.25 to 0.5?

Tags: r, raster, latitude-longitude, resolution

My data frame is based on 0.25 degree dataset and is composed of latitudes, longitudes and relevant temperature. And now I want to change the resolution from 0.25 to 0.5. For example, the latitudes and longitudes of my data frame are 70.5, 70.25, 70, 69.75, 69.5..., and now I just need integer and decimal part 0.5 coordinates like 70.5, 70, 69.5, 69...How can I do that easily?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `round_any` from `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
unrounded <- c(runif(10)*10)

> unrounded
 [1] 9.796907 4.237637 4.758592 1.109172 5.037765 3.077775 7.616236 3.872094
 [9] 3.471238 8.831574

rounded <- round_any(unrounded, 0.5)

> rounded
 [1] 10.0  4.0  5.0  1.0  5.0  3.0  7.5  4.0  3.5  9.0
```

As a `data.frame` you'll have to wrap it back into a `data.frame`:

```
unrounded2 <- data.frame(x = c(runif(10)*10))

> unrounded2
           x
1  6.1078737
2  1.8496701
3  3.5469245
4  9.7893189
5  0.5503520
6  8.4338650
7  2.5316328
8  0.1954177
9  4.0447613
10 7.9741839

rounded2 <- data.frame(x= round_any(unrounded2$x, 0.5))

> rounded2
      x
1   6.0
2   2.0
3   3.5
4  10.0
5   0.5
6   8.5
7   2.5
8   0.0
9   4.0
10  8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can round to 0.5 by first multiplying and then dividing by two.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- c(runif(10)*10)
x
# [1] 2.6550866 3.7212390 5.7285336 9.0820779 2.0168193 8.9838968 9.4467527 6.6079779 6.2911404 0.6178627
round(x * 2)/2
# [1] 2.5 3.5 5.5 9.0 2.0 9.0 9.5 6.5 6.5 0.5
```

As part of a data.frame

```
d <- data.frame(lon=x)
d$lon <- round(d$lon * 2) / 2
```